# Confused with recursive functions in python

Tags: python, recursion

Hey guys am new to python app development.i have came to learn about recrusive functions in python. The code which i have done

```
def something(a):
if a == 0:
    return 0
else:
    return 2 + something(a)
```

When i called the function like `pythons(5)` it calls me error like `TypeError: something() missing 1 required positional argument: 'b'`

I would like to do add two to a number like if i call `something(5)` it must return 5+2 = 7

I dunno why am getting this error.Hope you guys can help me out in solving this..I aplogise if this is a low grade question on so..

Any help would be appreciated ..Thanks in advance..

Comment: You can see that at the end you call `pythons(b-1)`.  You need to pass two arguments there.

Comment: you are calling pythons within pythons but only giving one argument

Comment: This is a strange recursive function. First of all you have passed only one parameter in the recursive call. Secondly it will always return 0. What is the purpose of the function?

Comment: Two things. 1. To understand recursion, you will first need to understand recursion. 2. This is less a question about recursion than about you not understanding basic function arguments/parameters in python, independently of recursion. I recommend spending time getting thoroughly comfortable on the basics in Python functions, and then get back to recursion.

Comment: Here is what you should do. In your question, include a few examples of sample input and expected output so that we understand better. Thank you. Like: input: `pythons(2,5)`, output:(???)

Comment: @user3783784, So pythons(2,5) returns 8, python(5,5) returns 20 (5*4) etc?

Comment: @user3783784, Or do you mean, python(2,5) should return 2*4*3*2*1?

Comment: @sshashank124 yeah if call python(5,5) it must return 20..

Comment: @sshashank124 i want to call it in a recrusive way not in actual way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your aim is to add two numbers recursively then this would be a more appropriate recursive function.

```
def add(a, b):
    if a == 0 and b ==0:
       return 0
    elif b == 0 and a>= 0:
       return 1 +add(a-1, 0)
    elif a ==0 and b>= 0:
       return 1 + add(0, b-1)
    else: return 2 + add(a-1, b-1)
```

Comment: its giving error like File "<pyshell#1>", line 3, in add
    return 1 + add(0, b-1) continously when i call the function with add(5,2)

Comment: @user3783784 try this

Comment: Glad to be of help. You might want to understand the algorithm and the concept of recursion in general, and accepting this as an answer :)

Comment: when i made a function like def names(a): return names(a+1) and called function like names(2) ..it gives me error ..can you tell me why it giving error like this ?

Comment: whenever you write a recursive function you must have a terminating condition so that the recursion can stop. in your case each function calls itself with a value greater than one. However it doesn't know when to stop. So it will keep calling itself till the end of time. However python checks if the recursion crosses a limit, it stops the call and raises an error

Comment: how can i overcome this error ..??..suppose if i want to add a number 1 with recrusion as i mentioned ..how can i do this ??

Comment: there is no recursive way to add 1 to a number. Unless you want to add it like say: 5+0.1+0.1+0.1+...0.1. You simply have to use 5+.1

Comment: i think you didnt understood me ..i will re edit my qus

Comment: hey now check the qus ..i have re ediitted

Comment: in that case 'def something(a): return 2 + a' would be enough.

Comment: 'def something(a): if a==0: return 0; else: return 2+1+something(a-1)' Here is your recursive method

Comment: thanks a lot bro ..when i used something(2) it shows 6 .can you tell me why it outputs six ??

Comment: oops! It should be 'def something(a): if a = 0: return 2; else: return 1+something(a-1)'

Answer (score 2):

That is because in your method, when you recursively call `pythons`, you are not passing two arguments. This is probably what you want:

```
def pythons(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return a * (b-1)
```

or simply (with same results):

```
def pythons(a,b):
    return a * (b-1)
```

Comment: it gives   File "<pyshell#9>", line 5, in names
    return a * names(a,b-1)

Comment: @user3783784, Please explain what you are intending to do with your program.

Comment: i just want to add two numbers with recrusive function...when i called the function like pythons(2,3) ..it gaves me error as i mentioned

Comment: @user3783784, Also, why is it `names`? Shouldn't it be `pythons`

Comment: @user3783784, Furthermore, if you are adding why is there a `*` in your code. Please explain your problem clearly. It is currently hard to understand

Comment: soory the error is File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in pythons
    return a * pythons(a,b-1)

Comment: it shows error like File "<pyshell#5>", line 5, in pythons
    return a * pythons(a,b-1) repeatedly

Comment: @user3783784  I think you have missed the point of using recursion.

Comment: @user3783784 ..can i do this with recrusive function ??

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues here. Firstly python code is whitespace sensitive when it comes to indentation (note that the question got edited, the formatting was not correct previously). Then secondly you need to match up the number of arguments provided to the functions:

```
def pythons(a,b):
    if a == 0:
        return a
    else:
        return a * pythons(a,b-1)
```

When you write `def pythons(a,b):` you are defining a function with the name `pythons` and you are specifying that it takes *exactly* 2 arguments, `a` and `b`. Previously you tried to call it with `pythons(b-1)`, the error message tells you exactly what has gone wrong, you only provided 1 argument when the function expected to get 2 arguments.